# Adwords / Landing Page keyword combinations

Tags: advertising, dynamic

I run a freelance web design business, and I am experimenting with running ads on key phrases like:

- website design for accountants
- accountant business website
- website design for dentists
- dentist business website

etc.

My problem is that I have to create an Adwords ad group for every profession I would like to advertise to, plus a landing page which contains a headline with the corresponding business type.

My question is: is there a way to create a single ad group, create some special key phrases in that ad group, e.g. `+website +design +for` and a single landing page where the the last word is captured and inserted in the landing page at specified points?

Comment: I don't have answer, but having more ad group is generally great idea. You can't capture same kind of leads from accountants and dentist. May be one perform better than second, so you will get idea what to scale more by targeting more audience. And may be some of your campaign will give you zero sales for some of ad group, how did you know which is bad and which performing good? So Always create variation/angles as much you can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

In your URL, add something like this to your URL:

```
http://yourdomain.com/landing-page/?key=designers
```

Then use server side script (PHP) to identify that GET variable `key` and change the header, title, and various elements on the page to match that particular variable.

For this to work you would **need to set a unique URL for each keyword in that ad group.**